# uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently I've started with Angular JS and I've created some routes that worked for some time. I'm not sure if I have done something wrong or not, but I'm getting a strange error and I'm not really sure what's wrong.

Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/248vJ/

im instantiating my app the normal way

```
var app = angular.module("upbis", ['ngRoute']);
```

This is the error:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=upbis&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0-beta.17%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dupbis%0A%20%20%20%20

[Link to error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=upbis&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0-beta.17%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dupbis%0A%20%20%20%20)

I really went through many solutions here on Stack but I couldn't find anything that solves my problem. Lost hours and couldn't find what's wrong.

Comment: You jsfiddle has a whole lot of references that aren't resolving - they are all relative to your local hard drive. If you fix them up, it should be easier to fix. It's most likely a module that you are not including properly. Also, use unminified angular, as it'll give you a human readable error message.

Comment: True but only things which are on my HD are script files, like Angular etc, I don't think that has to do anything with the problem, considering I've downloaded Angular and ngRoute from official Angular site. It's very strange what's happening, tried everything past 5 hours, no clue what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with dependency injection, I would recommend you to use a different approach injecting on controllers and config:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: "templates/feed.html",
        controller: 'FeedController'
    })

    .when('/bblog', {

        templateUrl: "templates/bblog.html",
        controller: 'BblogController'
    })

    .when('/marketplace', {

        templateUrl: "templates/marketplace.html",
        controller: 'MarketplaceController'
    })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

}]);


app.controller('FeedController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


}]);
```

(repeat this pattern for your other controllers as well)

Try this out and let me know, this way is minification safe, and it's probably whats messing with you.

Hope that helps, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help my friend, whatsoever, problem still persists and it's the same. I guess I need to do this from the scratch since error persists the same even if I remove my entire javascript file. It seams something is very messed up and not my JavaScript.

Comment: I'have "fixed it".
I simply removed Angular and AngularRoute files completely and reinstalled them via bower (bower install angular and bower install angular-route). This makes me sad thinking I've lost hours on this and error wasn't even there, just corrupted files.

Answer (score 0):

I'have "fixed it". I simply removed Angular and AngularRoute files completely and reinstalled them via bower (bower install angular and bower install angular-route). This makes me sad thinking I've lost hours on this and error wasn't even there, just corrupted files.